# SQL Server Mail senging error using sp_send_dbmail on gmail server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I am setting up a trigger based mail notification and while using it, I am also getting error.

The Profile setup is as bellow:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp @account_name               = 'TestMailAccount',
                                        @description                = 'Test Mail Account for sending notifications',
                                        @email_address              = 'my_gmail_id@gmail.com',
                                        @display_name               = 'Test Mail Notification',
                                        @username                   = 'my_gmail_id@gmail.com',
                                        @password                   = 'my_gmail_password',
                                        @mailserver_name            = 'smtp.gmail.com',
                                        @port                       = 587,
                                        @enable_ssl                 = 1;

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp @profile_name = 'TestMailProfile',
                                        @description = 'Main test profile used to send notification email';

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  @profile_name       = 'TestMailProfile',
                                                @account_name       = 'TestMailAccount',
                                                @sequence_number    = 2;

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
                                                @profile_name   = 'TestMailProfile',
                                                @principal_name = 'public',
                                                @is_default     = 0;
```

Now to send the mail, I executed:

```
DECLARE @mail_body NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @mail_body  = CONCAT(   N'<html>',
                                N'<body>',
                                    N'<h1>Test Mail</h1>',
                                N'</body>',
                            N'</html>');
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name   = 'TestMailProfile', 
        @recipients     = 'dest@gmail.com', 
        @subject        = N'DB Test Mail', 
        @body           = @mail_body,
        @body_format    = 'HTML';
```

After this, I checked the log:

```
select * from sysmail_event_log
```

The description shows:

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 42 (2020-03-01T18:41:09). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at).
```

I already have enabled google account's setting for using Less secure app access.

I am not sure what I am missing and any help will be highly appritiated.

Comment: have you tried with port 465?

Comment: @lptr: hadn't tried that, with Port 465, the error is " The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 43 (2020-03-01T19:25:06). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.)."

Comment: tested it with port 587 and it works

Comment: @lptr did you do something differently? If so, please share the script/settings etc?

Comment: i have used your setup script to the letter (simply changed the credentials for the account). (Less secure app access turned on too)

Comment: I could send the mail with the above settings with no changes but on a different network. I beleave the port(587) on my home network was blocked.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, write an **answer**. Once the waiting period is over, *accept* your own answer. Accepted answers are how we know that questions have been dealt with on SO.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : The question itself is complete solution for sending mail with gmail. I needed nothing to do to fix this. All the steps are complete. Only change of network solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Gmail settings look correct.  With the caveat of "try different port" (also mentioned in the comments of the original question above)

From https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2006/02/08/smarter-emailsmtp-setup-with-dotnet-configuration-sections-1-1-and-2-0/

```
<!–Note, with the 2.0 Framework, my tests show that gmail likes port 587–>

    <smtpServer 
        smtpServerName="smtp.gmail.com" 
        defaultEmailFrom="donotreply@gmail.com" 
        portNumber="465" 
        authenicationMode="SSL" 
        smtpUserName="mygmailaddress@gmail.com" 
        smtpUserPassword="mygmailpassword"/>
```

More likely, you probably have a port blockage.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

This is what I use to ping ports.  If you can install this small utility on the sql-server machine, it'll go a long way.

On the outside chance you're running sql-server on linux...you can "apt install curl" (or similar) and ping the port that way.

But sending email from sql-server has always been tricky.  You need the exact settings, and you need port (un)blocks.  Most times its the port(s) issue.

If the portqueryui tool above reports "blocked" or "filtered"...you may have to open an port on your computer.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028544/windows-10-turn-windows-defender-firewall-on-or-off

Your router/network can also block ports.  Again,the portqueryui tool is a quick way to test the path from the machine you're trying to get out to internet-land.

Comment: I am currently trying this on my home network and nothing should be blocked here (I think). About Linux, no I am using windows PC. About installing any add-on, I think that will not be possible as software will be installed by the installer and SQL configuration change is not possible.

Comment: Your individual computer can block the port.  The tool I reference is a simple way to check.

Comment: The result from the tool is:
Starting portqry.exe -n smtp.gmail.com -e 587 -p TCP ...
Querying target system called:
smtp.gmail.com
Attempting to resolve name to IP address...
Name resolved to 108.177.125.109
querying...
TCP port 587 (unknown service): LISTENING
portqry.exe -n smtp.gmail.com -e 587 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000000.